# problem in saving Account settings [Email template]

Tags: 7, users, database, tokens

when i tried change some words in email template that was sent when user register in the website or canceled or verified or ... etc 
after i change it i have an error in saving it

[image]

i tried to build my custom token but i think it is not the right solutions for this bug

any one know any suggestions about this issue .

Comment: Those are, by default, valid tokens.  How did you build the custom token that you're referring to?

Comment: @ChrisRockwell   i know it is the default token but when i saw this error i thought to build custom token using hook_tokens()

Comment: i tried to remove every token like [user:login-url] ... and put my custom token [custom:login-url] For example but it doesn't work also

Comment: Sorry, just trying to wrap my head around it - did you implement `hook_token()` after the error?  If so, you should disable your custom module, any one that implements the hook, flush the cache and re-try.

Comment: yes i already disabled my custom module but nothing new :(

Comment: Which version of Drupal and Token?

Comment: Drupal 7.19  and the token module version = "7.x-1.4"

Comment: I can't reproduce, sorry.  The next steps I would take (after ensuring cache was cleared and testing again) would be to disable all contrib modules other than token, check if it works. If so, one-by-one, turn them back on and keep checking.

Comment: you are right the problem in token module . but why ??

Comment: Upgrade the module or re-install the same version.

Comment: i delete this module and re-install it again from the contrib but nothing new :(

Comment: Nothing in the logs (admin/reports/dblog)?  Short of giving me a copy via [Backup & Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) I'm not sure I can help :(